# How to add tag to wrap table row if specific td class within it found

Tags: jquery

I've seen others who have used jQuery to add a class and I need to do the same based on id or class found within it.

Here is sample HTML

```
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td>56</td>
<td>Speed Racer</td>
<td id="season2013">2013</td>
<td>14</td>
</tr>
```

I need to add a class or id tag to all tr when any of the td has in id of #season2013
I don't think what i have below will work , but was hoping for some help.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $( '#season2013' ).wrap( '<tr class="newclass"></tr>' );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Note that element `id`s must be unique on the page. If you have more than one td with the id `season2013`, I would suggest using a class instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$(function(){
    $('#season2013').closest('tr').addClass('newclass');
});
```

Since your table already has `<tr>` tags, you don't need to wrap a new `<tr>`, just add the class to the `<tr>` that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `has` selector:

```
$("tr").has("#season2013").addClass("newclass");
```

You won't need to `wrap` the `td` in a new `tr` tag since it already has a `tr` parent. Instead add the class to that `tr` directly.